# Taking hours to iterate 300 million mongo db records

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I'm iterating over the whole mongo documents from a mongo slave using mongo java API.
Mongo Server:  2.4.10
Number of records in slave: 300 million.
I've one mongo master, one mongo slave.
(No sharding done)

The mongo slave gets replicated very high frequency 2000 insertions and deletions every 10 seconds.

The iteration is taking more than 10 hours.
My goal is to fetch each record in the collection and create a csv and load it to redshift.

```
DB db = null;
DBCursor cursor = null;
mongo = new MongoClient(mongoHost);
mongo.slaveOk();
db = mongo.getDB(dbName);
DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection(dbCollectionName);
cursor = dbCollection.find();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject resultObject = cursor.next();
    String uid = (String) ((Map) resultObject.get("user")).get("uid");
    String category = (String) resultObject.get("category");
    resultMap.put(uid, category);

    if (resultMap.size() >= csvUpdateBatchSize) {
        //store to a csv - append to an existing csv
    }
```

}

is there a way to bring down the iteration time to below 1 hours?
Infrastructure changes can be done too ..Like increasing shards.
Please suggest.

Comment: No code here. What are you doing exactly and why are you iterating the collection? If we had some idea of what you are doing we might be able to suggest a different way. You should edit your question to add this.

Comment: It seems like you need only user.uid and category. So, why not pull only those two records when you fire a find and also create a compound index on two of them.

Comment: all the records in the collection have both the fields...and an index is present on uid field. I even tried with query {"user.uid":{$ne:null}}. still no improvement.

Comment: I don't think mongo loads the whole result set in one go....It gets the resultset in chunks..there is a get more operation running when i checked with db.getCurrentOp() on slave...please correct me if I'm wrong. I've not seen any memory related issues on my server which is running the above code. –

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered performing a parallel mongoexport on your collection?
If you have a way to partition your data with a query (something like modulo over an id or indexed field) and pass this as a standard input to your program.

Your program then will handle each document as a JSON row, which you can load to a designated object representing document structure with GSON or some other similar library
and eventually run your logic on that object.

Using mongoexport and adding parallelism can improve your performance greatly.